# Best way to count the number of entries, grouped by a foreign key and which have dates within the last two years in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join

I am trying to write the SQL for a database project and basically I have a table called `Organization` which has an attribute called `Project_id` which is a foreign key of a table called `Project`. `Project` has an  attribute called `year`. I want to find the `Organizations` which had more than 5 distinct projects assigned to them within any two year period but I am having trouble with it. I tried doing an inner join on `Organization` and `Project` but I am pretty much stuck there. If I group by `year` I won't be able to distinguish Organizations and if I group by `Organization_id` I can't distinguish between years.

Is this even possible in SQL?

Comment: Group by both organization AND year: `GROUP BY organization.id, project.year`

Comment: Maybe it' s just me but `Organization` having a FK `Project_id` and at the same time having many `Project`s sounds like a not-so-good design.

Comment: @Filburt This is a simplified version of the structure.